# Oracle SQL use previous column value to lookup next row

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, lookup

What I currently have:

```
ID  FROM_REF TO_REF
--- -------- ----
1   1        10
1   2        3
1   3        4
1   3        5
1   5        6
1   6        7
1   7        9
1   8        11
1   9        8
1   10       2
```

What's needed is the SORT column which I can use to sort according later on:

```
ID  FROM_REF TO_REF SORT
--- -------- ----   ----
1   1        10     1
1   10       2      2
1   2        3      3
1   3        4      4
1   4        5      5
1   5        6      6
1   6        7      7
1   7        9      8
1   9        8      9
1   8        11     10
```

NOTE: TO_REF column indicate next FROM_REF.

How do I write SQL to achieve the **SORT** column as result?

Please help.

Comment: According your expected result, this row `1   3        5` should be `1   4        5`

Comment: What is the logic behind how you want the new sort column to be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple hierarchical query, I presume.

```
SQL> with test (from_ref, to_ref) as
  2  (select 1, 10 from dual union
  3   select 2, 3  from dual union
  4   select 3, 4  from dual union
  5   select 4, 5  from dual union
  6   select 5, 6  from dual union
  7   select 6, 7  from dual union
  8   select 7, 9  from dual union
  9   select 8, 11 from dual union
 10   select 9, 8  from dual union
 11   select 10, 2 from dual
 12  )
 13  select from_ref, to_ref, level rn
 14  from test
 15  connect by  from_ref = prior to_ref
 16  start with from_ref = (select min(from_ref) from test);

  FROM_REF     TO_REF         RN
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10          1
        10          2          2
         2          3          3
         3          4          4
         4          5          5
         5          6          6
         6          7          7
         7          9          8
         9          8          9
         8         11         10

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RECURSIVE function.

> ```
> WITH X (ID, FROM_REF, TO_REF) AS
> (
>     SELECT ID, FROM_REF, TO_REF
>     FROM   tbl 
>     WHERE  FROM_REF = 1
>    UNION ALL
>     SELECT tbl.ID, tbl.FROM_REF, tbl.TO_REF
>     FROM   tbl
>     JOIN   X
>     ON     tbl.ID = X.ID
>     AND    tbl.FROM_REF = X.TO_REF
> )
> SELECT ID, FROM_REF, TO_REF
> FROM   X
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | FROM_REF | TO_REF
> -: | -------: | -----:
>  1 |        1 |     10
>  1 |       10 |      2
>  1 |        2 |      3
>  1 |        3 |      4
>  1 |        4 |      5
>  1 |        5 |      6
>  1 |        6 |      7
>  1 |        7 |      9
>  1 |        9 |      8
>  1 |        8 |     11
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3bfb2c91f39c6eaa5c646b2e9378e041)*